# Codility MinAbsSumOfTwo in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with a challenge from Codility and I can't understand why the `MinAbsSumOfTwo` challenge works with the same algorithm in C#, but does not work in Javascript.

Here is the [link](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingZUET8T-49U/) to the result page for the implementation in JS (54/100).

And here is the [link](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingENQP3Q-SPA/) to the result page for the implementation in C# (100/100).

I tried to simulate the `extreme_large` and the `arithmetic_medium` tests in my machine, but both gives me the expected result:

```javascript
  it('should return 1002 for arithmetic medium', () =>
  {
    const arithmetic = []
    let value = -5010000

    for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      arithmetic.push(value += 1002)

    assert.equal(solution(arithmetic), 1002)
  })

  it('should return 1999999994 for sequence of MAX_INT', () =>
  {
    const maxIntSequence = []

    for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
      maxIntSequence.push(999999997)

    assert.equal(solution(maxIntSequence), 1999999994)
  })
```

I really appreciate if anyone could help!

Comment: your `absOrder` method is invalid; [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects the comparator function to return an number, not a boolean

Comment: you're absolutely right! thank you so much! please make this an answer so I can mark it right :)

Comment: can you explain the reason behind the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `absOrder` method is invalid; [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects the comparator function to return a number, not a boolean:

```
A.sort((a,b) => Math.abs(a) - Math.abs(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            function solution(A) {
                // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
                var min =+Infinity,sum;
                for(var i =0 ;i< A.length ;i++){
                    for(var j=0 ;j< A.length ;j++){
                        if(i > j) continue;
                        sum = Math.abs(A[i] + A[j]);
                        min = Math.min(sum,min);
                    }
                }
                return min;
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.